# Solved - Inserting content inside the WordPress loop

Tags: loop, plugin-jetpack

I currently trying to insert a block of custom code inside the WordPress posts loop which is using JetPack's infinite scroll functionality. In theory, this should be quite simple but is proving otherwise.

this is what I have currently written:

```
    <?php
        $count = 0;
        while( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content-post', get_post_format() );
            if ($count === 4) {
                get_template_part( 'block-one', get_post_format() );
            }

            $count ++;
        endwhile;
    ?>
```

So, if the count is at `4` insert the custom block. However, when I look at my homepage, I get this view:

[image]

The custom code block has been added before the posts. I can't quite find out why.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is the content.php:

```
<a class="post-container-home" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div
        class="post-image"
        style="background: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>)"
    >
    </div>
    <div class="post-info-home">
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>Title</p>
        <div class="post-time">
            <h3>min read</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here is block-one.php:

```
<div id="newsletter" class="post-container-home">
    <img src="/theme-new/wp-content/themes/theme-blog-new/img/subscribe.png" alt="subscribe">
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the individual template parts, but it's likely that the `block-one` part is `echo`ing or directly outputing, while the `content-post` is `return`ing.

Comment: @WebElaine Added those two templates to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fool.

I just noticed I'm trying to use `content-post` when I changed it to just `content`.

All working now.

Sorry.